# Returning the values of a table view in one window to a line edit in another

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tableview, qlineedit

The following code is used by me in order to send the value in a table view in one window to the line edit in another window. but i get an error! how can i correct it?

```
void firstWindow::on_tableView_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{

    QString val=ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();
    firstWindow conn;
     conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("Select MESSAGE_ID from Message where  MESSAGE_ID='"+val+"'");
    if(qry.exec())
    {
        while(qry.next())
        {
           Window2 a;

          ui->message->setText(qry.value(0).toString());

    }
}


    conn.connClose();


}
```

here firstwindow is one class which has a connOpen() method to connect to a database( works properly), when the user clicks a row retrieved from the database i want it to appear in a line edit named message in a window which belongs to a class named window2. 
But I get an error stating that message is not a member of firstWindow class! How can i correct this issue?

Comment: Which line generates that error message ?, also can show the complete code of the class `firstWindow`.

Comment: Is message defined in the same ui file as tableView? From your description I would expect it is not. And you should use signals and slots to solve the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc " ui->message->setText(qry.value(0).toString());: this generates the error because I think message is a line edit componennent belonging to the window2 class but its done inside a method in firstwindow class

Comment: @drescherjm message is a line edit

Comment: show the complete code of the class firstWindow

Comment: ***message is a line edit*** Should be very easy to use signals and slots for that. Create a signal with a QString parameter in firstWindow connect that to a slot on secondWindow (again with a QString parameter). In the slot update the message directly.